# How to update partial of profile using Firestore

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm creating Edit profile page using Firestore.

When user navigate to the Edit profile, the user have their profile. Because they already registered.
User can change all items in their profile in edit page.
But of course they can change partial of their profile.

How do I detect data they did change?

First I thought I would use update method below

```
func updateProfile(user: User){
  let user = db.collection("user").document("user-id")


user.updateData([
    "name":user.name,
     "profile":user.profile ?? ""
     "phone":user.phone ?? "",
]) { err in
    if let err = err {
        print("Error updating document: \(err)")
    } else {
        print("Document successfully updated")
    }
   }
}
```

It is possible user did change only their name.
But this way can update not changed data.
I mean I will update all datas user didn't change.
How do I detect the only data user did change.

Comment: What's wrong with what you have now? Overwriting document fields with the same data has no effect and shouldn't matter at all.